# A completely positive -> $P^TAP$ complitely positive

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations

Let $A$ be a symmetric $n \times n$ matrix. If $P$ is an $n \times n$ permutation matrix, then $A$ is completely positive if and only if $P^TAP$ is completely positive.

Geometrically is the statement quite obvious. When checking whether $v_1,...v_n$ can be embedded in a nonnegative orthant of some $R^k$, neither the order of the vectors not their length meter.

How can I prove this rigorously?

Answer (score 4):

If $A$ is completely positive then there exists an $m \times n$ matrix $B$ with nonnegative elements such that $A = B^TB$.

For any permutation matrix $P$ we have $$P^TAP = P^TB^TBP = (BP)^T(BP)$$
and $BP$  has nonnegative elements.